# Deleting values from PostgreSQL database in FME?

Tags: postgresql, fme-form

I have a PostgreSQL database which I initialized through FME. What I want to do now is to delete some values from the database. 
How can I do that? I am trying to use SQLExecutor but I don't know what to put in the input parameter called initiator. 
Actually I don't quite understand why I need an input parameter. I just want to connect to the database and delete some values from the table.

What would be the workflow for this?

Comment: The undesirability of having question titles pre-fixed by what is effectively a duplication of the main tag has been discussed by the founder of Stack Overflow/Exchange at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10651/215590

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go with the SQLExecuter, the initiator would need to be a list of database values [keys] you want to delete.
Then using something similar the SQL statement below to execute the delete query should work.

DELETE FROM table
 WHERE key = '@Value(key)';

Or you can use the [DatabaseDeleter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/2015.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Desktop_Help.htm#cshid=fmx_DatabaseDeleter)

Comment: Thanks. So what kind of transformer/reader should I make in order to have this list? Could it be also an excel file?

Comment: Yes Any reader that can carry the attribute value keys to delete.And yes excel works.

Comment: This SQL can also be placed in a writer (under advanced settings) to execute before/after the write - good for updates as well as deletions.

Comment: You would connect a flow of data to the transformer, if you wanted to run the command once for each feature. Otherwise, to run the transformer just once, connect a Creator transformer to it.