# Turn a specific attribute of all features into a list in FME

Tags: fme-form

I am trying to update an SQL table using the SQLExecuter. I do have all the features the table should be updated with, but what I ideally need is a list of IDs from those features, since the only thing I need to do here is to delete them.

Hence, I was aiming for something like "FROM table DELETE WHERE id IN (list of IDs)".

How can I add all the IDs of my features to an comma-separated list?

Comment: There are also options under the Writers to update/delete or use the DatabaseDeleter https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/145096/deleting-values-from-postgresql-database-in-fme for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Aggregator](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/aggregator.htm) can be used to merge features and concatenate the values of a field.

- Set Aggregation Mode to Attributes Only.
- Set Accumulation Mode to Drop Incoming Attributes.
- In Attributes to Concatenate, select the ID field you want to concatenate.
- Set the Seperator Character to ,

Comment: Cheers Niels! Worked like a charm.